# When condition is true use prior value [SQL]

Tags: sql, presto

When `customer_status` is 1 and not more blank select the `previous customer_tag` value and create a new column showing the previous tag

Sample table

```
date         customer_id  customer_status  customer_tag
2020-01-01   9493                          inactive_customer
2020-01-02   9493                          inactive_customer
2020-01-03   9493                          inactive_customer
2020-01-04   9493         1                active_customer
2020-01-05   9493         1                active_customer
```

Desired output table

```
date         customer_id  customer_status  customer_tag          previous_customer_tag
2020-01-01   9493                          inactive_customer     
2020-01-02   9493                          inactive_customer
2020-01-03   9493                          inactive_customer
2020-01-04   9493         1                active_customer       inactive_customer
2020-01-05   9493         1                active_customer       inactive_customer
```

Comment: can we define this column in the select query as `case when (customer_status = 1 and customer_tag = 'active_customer') then 'inactive_customer' end as "previous_customer_tag" `?

Comment: Why is previous_customer_tag = inactive_customer for 2020-01-05? Shouldnt it be active_customer as it was the customer_tag for 2020-01-04?

Answer (score 0):

I made the following assumptions:

1. You need to update your existing table accordingly and don't just need a SELECT statement here.
2. `customer_status` column can be NULL.
3. `previous_customer_tag` column can be NULL.

Furthermore, I changed the name of date column to `customer_date` because date is a keyword.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
ADD COLUMN previous_customer_tag varchar(255) NULL;

UPDATE CUSTOMERS 
SET previous_customer_tag = CASE WHEN customer_status = 1 THEN 'inactive_customer' ELSE NULL END;
```

Here is the complete [solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6217a5/1) implemented by me. I hope it helps. Please mark this answer as correct if it helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lag`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag) window function and conditionally use it's value as `previous_customer_tag` with [`if`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#id0):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset ( date, customer_id, customer_status, customer_tag) AS (
    VALUES
(date '2020-01-01', 9493, null, 'inactive_customer'),
(date '2020-01-02', 9493, null, 'inactive_customer'),
(date '2020-01-03', 9493, null, 'inactive_customer'),
(date '2020-01-04', 9493, 1, 'active_customer'),
(date '2020-01-05', 9493, 1, 'active_customer')
) 

--query
select *,
    if(
        customer_status = 1,
        lag(customer_tag) over (partition by customer_id order by date)
    ) previous_customer_tag
from dataset
```

Output:

| date | customer_id | customer_status | customer_tag | previous_customer_tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 9493 |  | inactive_customer |  |
| 2020-01-02 | 9493 |  | inactive_customer |  |
| 2020-01-03 | 9493 |  | inactive_customer |  |
| 2020-01-04 | 9493 | 1 | active_customer | inactive_customer |
| 2020-01-05 | 9493 | 1 | active_customer | active_customer |